# running bash commands in cnf template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have completed the first few steps as mentioned in this article.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/running-bash-commands-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/

But I am getting an error at this:

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
--stack-name comandrunner-test-iops \
--template-file ./examples/commandrunner-example-iopscalc-template.yaml
```

> The following resource(s) failed to create: [IopsCalculator]. Rollback
> requested by user.

How do I know why the stack is not successfully created in this case?

Comment: There should be more information in the stack events. You can retrieve these by looking at the web console, or running `aws cloudformation describe-stack-events` against the stack.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't seem to match the actual question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation for this command:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html

There is nothing really helpful there. Nothing in the parent command neither.

The best option is to look at the CloudFormation console. Sometimes Cloud Formation doesn't help too much around this type of errors.